# Кэширование .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, кэширование

Можно ли установить кэширование на длительный срок с помощью Cache-Control или Expires (исключительно для PageSpeed Insights), но при этом указать FileETag MTime Size на случай если файлы изменились до указанного срока (для пользователей)? Используется Apache.

вот примерный код, но желаемый результат не достигнут, браузер берёт файлы из кэша...

```
FileETag MTime Size

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
#кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=120"
</FilesMatch>
#кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=120"
</FilesMatch>
#кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
<FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=120"
</FilesMatch>
#отключить кэширование
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
    Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
```

если такой вариант не возможен то есть ли альтернатива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было принято решение устанавливать кэш с помощью Cache-Control, а в случае изменения файла менять URL'ы добавляя версию через знак вопроса...

Взято отсюда: http://www.plam.ru/compinet/razgoni_svoi_sait/p5.php
(параграф Форсированный сброс кэша)